# Connecting with Huawei E3372 on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, huawei-mobile-services

I try to connect to Internet with an LTE Stick from Huawei (e3372). I installed usb-modeswitch, ppp and wvdial. modewswitch is working correctly. The device is mounted on /dev/ttyUSB0 where i am able to send AT commands. I want to connect with wvdial but it always say "The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)" 
The console print of my wvdial command is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","drei.at"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","drei.at"
OK
^DSFLOWRPT:00000062,00000000,00000000,0000000000000000,0000000000000084,00000000,00000000
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Thu Mar  2 14:08:21 2017
--> Pid of pppd: 1142
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: ���v[08]��[01]
--> pppd: ���v[08]��[01]
--> pppd: ���v[08]��[01]
--> pppd: ���v[08]��[01]
--> pppd: ���v[08]��[01]
--> Disconnecting at Thu Mar  2 14:08:52 2017
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATZ
^CCaught signal 2:  Attempting to exit gracefully...
--> Modem not responding.
--> Disconnecting at Thu Mar  2 14:09:00 2017
```

My wvdial config file:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","drei.at"
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 9600
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
Password = ;
Username = ;
Stupid Mode = 1
Dialer Attemps = 2
Carrier Check = off
```

What cause the ppp daemon to hang up?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old topic, but I would like to contribute as I found myself in trouble with this particular modem and the problem I had and I can see in this post too is using ttyUSB0, if someone ever has that problem again: try changing to ttyUSB1. Modem communicates as two devices, both accept commands, but ttyUSB0 not only hangs up, but also freezes modem!