# No connection with Huawei E3372 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to connect to the internet with a Huawei E3372h-153. The blue LED is constantly lit indicating it is connected but when I open a browser and go to a website I get: "This site can't be reached".

I have also tried to plug it into a Windows 10 laptop and after running the .exe file it works perfectly.

The Raspberry Pi 4 model B runs Raspbian release 10.

I have installed ppp, usb-modeswitch, and wvdial. When I use "lsusb" I get:

```
    Bus 001 Device 012: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
```

which as I understand it, means it is in the right mode. Furthermore when I use "ifconfig" I get; eth0, lo, ppp0, wlan0, and wwan0, and they are all "UP" and especially ppp0 and wwan0 are also "RUNNING".

When I run "sudo wvdial" I get the output:

```
--> Wvdial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","bredband.tre.dk"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","bredband.tre.dk"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected. Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Thu Oct 31 21:43:00 2019
--> Pid of pppd: 2441
--> Using interface ppp0
--> local  IP address 109.56.191.78
--> remote IP address 10.64.64.64
--> primary   DNS address 95.209.200.69
--> secondary DNS address 95.209.200.70
```

I've followed this link: [Connecting with Huawei E3372 on RaspberryPi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557913/connecting-with-huawei-e3372-on-raspberrypi)

and this link: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79272/problems-with-huawei-e3372-usb-modem-with-raspberry-pi-3

My /etc/wvdial.conf contains the following:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","bredband.tre.dk"
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 9600
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/tttyUSB1
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
Password = ;
Username = ;
Stupid Mode = 1
Dialer Attempts = 2
Carrier Check = off
```

So I would expect that I can connect to the internet but as mentioned when I open a browser and e.g. try to go to google.com I get "This site can't be reached".

Does anyone know what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...

I found this:
http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2756 (1)

Which after googling the network manager lead me to:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29783/how-to-setup-network-manager-on-raspbian (2)

After installing network manager and it didn't seem to work I followed the answer by giox069 (2) which solved the problem.

Then I could open network manager and create a new broadband connection and it now works.